# Resolving parent version using property specified in parent pom at relativePath using Maven

Tags: git, maven-3

While working on big hierarchical Maven projects and Git branches, it's very difficult to handle git merges(as the poms might have different versions). This is even more difficult when you have 200+ Maven projects within the repo.

Is there a way to specify the version in the top level parent and inherit it into the other sub-parents and modules?

For example, with the below simple structure

```
- parent
|- pom.xml
|- child
   |-pom.xml
```

I was able to get it working using the below parent and child pom files

parent pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.coderplus</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
  <master.version>${project.version}</master.version>
  </properties>
  <modules>
    <module>child</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

child pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.coderplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>${master.version}</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>child</artifactId>
</project>
```

(tested on Maven 3.3.3)

Are there any potential problems in using this approach(may be `maven-release-plugin` related issues)?